# Java : write scala map function with canBuildFrom

Tags: java, scala

I want to convert a scala function that replaces the age of a certain person in a scala `Map<String,String>` (which is name -> age) : `map.map(e => if (e._1 == "Tom") (e._1, "52") else e)`

Now I need to write the same function in java, I also have a scala map (`scala.collection.Map`) as input, I checked in javadoc the method map.map(..)  has this signature :

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That])
```

So the function f I write like this :

```
    AbstractFunction1 f = new AbstractFunction1<Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple2<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, String> apply(Tuple2<String, String> e) {
            if (e._1.equals("Tom")) {
                return new Tuple2<>(e._1, "52");
            }
            return e;
        }
    };
```

But I have no idea what I should put in `CanBuildFrom`. I searched some posts but never found something that works for me.

Does someone know how to do this properly with .map() or there is some other workaround for this kind of usage in Java ? Note : I can convert the scala map into Java map first but it's definitely not something I will do because the return value of the function is also a scala map.

Comment: So you are looping over the keys of a Map to replace a single value?

Comment: Yes that is the goal of this function

Comment: But not a single value, there may be many values to replace

Comment: Can't you convert this map to Java map and work with it? It would be much easier.

Comment: @Ivan Kurchenko Yes I can but the return type is also scala map, it's a udf. It'll be very ugly if I convert first to java then convert back to scala map

Comment: If you have a **Scala** `Map` then you already have the **Scala** library in scope I would just write all your **Scala** operations in a **Scala** file to limit the interaction with **Java**. - In any case, the conversions do not copy data and if you modify in place then everything would be very efficient.